# Matplotlib.pyplot scatter-plot with numpy input different values makes separate points for each value

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scatter-plot

Normally the x and y input values are merged into a coordinate point.
Using list, it's ok:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
a = [5,6]
plt.scatter(a[0],a[1])
plt.show() # shows one point at 5,6. OK
```

Using numpy with same values in x and y:

```
b=np.array([[4],[4]])
plt.scatter(b[:,0],b[:,0])
plt.show() # shows one point at 4,4. OK
```

But using numpy with different values in x and y:

```
c=np.array([[5],[6]])
plt.scatter(c[:,0],c[:,0])
plt.show() # shows points at 5,5 and 6,6. Problem
```

Comment: What did you expect the results to be? What do you want them to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the column vector for `c`, calling `c[:,0]` gives:

```py
print(c[:,0])  # array([5, 6])
```

When creating a scatterplot, the first argument gives the x-values and the second gives the y-values. So, you are setting the x-values to be `[5, 6]` and your y-values to be `[5, 6]`. The points are plotted matching one-to-one. Therefore, the first values of x and y are `[5, 5]` and the second values are `[6, 6]`, hence the plot results.

To get a single point at `(5, 6)`, you do what you did with `a`, namely,

```py
plt.scatter(c[0], c[1])
```

Comment: Array c.shape is (2,1). It is supposed to have many points. I'm showing only one, but it doesn't show correct. This "problem" occurs in Visual Studio, PyCharm, and Colab. How do I input numpy with 5,6 same as with a list 5,6?

Comment: It's still not clear what you expected it to show. My answer explains why it shows what it does. And in your post, you said that the `[4, 4]` example has one point, but that's wrong, it has two points both at `[4, 4]`.

Comment: A point is made of x and y coordinate values. If x and y are 4,4 there should be one point. If the x and y are 5,6 there should be one point.

Comment: If you read my answer, you'll see that that isn't how it works. You pass the x and y coordinates separately, and then it plots them one-to-one. You passed 5, 6 for each of x and y, so the matching results in 5, 5 and 6, 6. And as I said for the 4, 4 example, you passed that for both x and y, so you actually have two points (one on top of the other) both at 4, 4.

Comment: I provided an example (list a) where the x and y values (5 and 6) make one visible point in a matplotlib scatter-plot at 5,6. I'm asking how to do that with a numpy input.

Comment: @user3808252 That was not clear. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

c = np.array([[5], [6]])

# Create a 1x2 array with the first element being x-coordinates and the second being y-coordinates
coordinates = np.hstack((c, c))  # Creates: [[5, 5], [6, 6]]

plt.scatter(coordinates[:, 0], coordinates[:, 1])
plt.show()
```